# Searching markers from text in snippet

Tags: android, google-maps, textbox

I need to add to my application a text box where I type address (street, city) and then app will displayed markers fulfilling this criteria. Any ideas or tutorials? My markers have adress written in snippet. Sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First pass address from text box to given method below which will give you latitude and longitude of that address and through this latitude and longitude you can place the marker on map.

```
 //----Coding to get latitude and longitude from address----

     private void searchFromLocationName(String name){
         try {

             Geocoder myGeocoder = new Geocoder(this);
          List<Address> result = myGeocoder.getFromLocationName(name, 5);

          if ((result == null)||(result.isEmpty()))
          {
           Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Sorry!No matches were found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
          else{
           String stringResult = "";
           for (int i =0; i < result.size(); i++){

            stringResult += "latitude: " + result.get(i).getLatitude() + "\n"
              + "longitude: " + result.get(i).getLongitude() + "\n";

           }

          }


         } catch (IOException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();

         }
        }
```

And to show address on snippet:-

```
overlayItemsList.add(new OverlayItem(geoPoint, title, address));
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep all your `Marker`s in `ArrayList<Marker>` then loop over them and change visibility.

```
for (Marker marker : allMarkers) {
    String snippet = marker.getSnippet();
    boolean match = snippet.contains(myText);
    marker.setVisible(match);
}
```